# WP - temp dir not writable with 777

Tags: wordpress, configuration, fwrite, temp

I thought I will solve that myself, but after few hours I don't know what to do else.

I have WP 4.9.8 project (skeleton) without any plugin and theme. I am trying to instal some plugins and upload images, but it still says

```
Missing a temporary folder
```

I already set **WP_TEMP_DIR** by many ways, but unsuccessfully. When I call:

```
var_dump(get_temp_dir());
```

in current theme **functions.php** file it gives me concrete folder. I already changed mode to 777. But nothing changed.
When I put:

```
file_put_contents(get_temp_dir() . 'test.txt', 'testing');
```

to **functions.php** it successfully write to **test.txt** file.

I also tried to restart PHP(5.6) and Nginx...

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

**Check directory owner.**

the directory must owned by Nginx.

Try this code, change the path to your temp path

```
chown www-data:www-data /path/to/wp-temp-direcotry/ -R
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I forgot to write I also already tried to change owner and group to www-data or just www. Still same. But I think if the folder has 777 mode, this doesn't take effect. Is possible to find out, where the error happen?

Comment: The problem was symlinks. My web server redirect request to specific release of app by symlink and when I removed symlink and target release directly it solves my problem.